Elliptic curve with two points satisfying certain ratio condition
Consider an Elliptic curve $E: y^2=x(x-a)(x-b)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose that

$(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ are on $E$
$x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{Q}$
$y_1,y_2\notin\mathbb{Q}(y_1\neq y_2)$

My question is as follows.

Is $\frac{y_1}{y_2}\in\mathbb{Q}$ possible?

If $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ are rational points of $E$, obviously it is possible. If $y_1,y_2\notin\mathbb{Q}$, their form should be $y_1=p\sqrt{q}, y_2=\sqrt{q}$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Can anyone please give an example or prove that this is impossible?

Not to be pedantic, but you haven't specified that $y_1, y_2$ must be distinct, so there's an example

Sorry, I edited it

$a=1$, $b=2$, $x_1=3$, $y_1=\sqrt6$, $x_2=4$, $y_2=2\sqrt6$, $y_1/y_2=1/2$.
